# How to delete Hive default partition value, __HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, aws-glue

I am using Glue metestore for Hive and I have AWS EMR cluster to query and modify Hive tables.

My data for this resides in S3

I have 3 partition columns:

```
yr_no: int, month_no: int, uniq_id: int
```

However I have some files that have NULL values for these which Hive sets the partition value for yr_no and month_no as **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

But since yr_no and month_no are both ints, I cannot easily drop those partitions.

I tried below formats:

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITION(yr_no=__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__);
ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITION(yr_no<1);
```

First command complained since the column is int and 2nd complained about the syntax <

Is there a simple way to drop it on yr_no=**HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION** or month_no=**HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `show partitons` at first. And then, use `desc formatted partition(yr_no=xxx,month_no=xxxx)` to see the detail informations.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following and it will work.

```
ALTER TABLE table DROP PARTITION(yr_no='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');
```

Comment: I tried this variation as well but in glue metastore, it is complaining that this is a string and not integer since yr_no is an Int. But is Hive metastore it worked fine